# How to run javascript inside an iframe created within a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have this code inside my content.js file in a chrome extension:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("frame.html");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
document
    .getElementById("store")
    .addEventListener("click", console.log("clicked"));
```

This frame will render over the web page the user is viewing. The frame I am trying to render has this button:

```
<button
    type="button"
    id="store"
    name="store"
>Yes</button>
```

I would like to see the log to the console when the button is clicked. However, I get
`Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

I understand that the event listener can not be added because it cannot find the button in the document. I also understand that I cannot call javascript functions from withing the frame.html file because it is blocked by the chrome extension in order to prevent csrf attacks.

How can I add javascript functionality to the buttons inside my iframe?

Comment: The iframe is a standard DOM page so simply add `<script src=frame.js></script>` in frame.html and add frame.js in web_accessible_resources.

Comment: yep that did it, thanks